# Unfortunately, it looks like your team settings don't allow adding apps right now. Talk to your team owner about adjusting your settings.--In MS Teams

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

I have a channel related to my client in MS teams along with few other mail id's as the member to that channel, when I log in from my mail id which also a member in that channel is not able to see 'add more apps' option in the front page of MS teams, when i go to channel--manage team--apps I could see error as per below screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0tNn.png)

when I log in from other id's I could see all my apps inside the 'add more apps' ,refer to below screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0vEB.png)

We are deploying the application using 'teams-developer portal'  and permission and user related info/instance is present in the 'azure active directory'.

Comment: Please go through [Manage apps for Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-apps) to get an idea on the app permission policies.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Moving my comment to Answer for more visibility.

Please go through [Manage apps for Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-apps) to get an idea on the app permission policies.